# The second column always appears lower than the first one in the multicol environment

Tags: vertical-alignment, multicol

I need to make a two column document (on a landscape format sheet), but the second column appears in a lower position than the first one. I wrote "always" in the title because it also happens when I use the `minipage` environment to split the page in two columns. Here's an example, how can I solve this problem? Thank you. Luigi

[image]

Here's the input file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,multicol}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{}{1em}{}
\title{Nuovi e vecchi fatti stilizzati}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\maketitle
\begin{multicols}{2}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section*{Kaldor Facts 1961}
\begin{enumerate}
\item La produttività del lavoro è cresciuta a un tasso sostenuto
\item Il rapporto capitale/lavoro è cresciuto a un tasso sostenuto
\item Il tasso di profitto sul capitale è stato stabile nei paesi sviluppati
\item Il rapporto capitale/output è rimasto stabile
\item Le quote di profitto e salario sono state stabili
\item Vi sono state differenze dei tassi di crescita tra paesi nell'ordine del 2\%-5\%
\end{enumerate}
\columnbreak
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section*{New Kaldor Facts 2009 - Jones, Romer}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item La produttività del lavoro è cresciuta a un tasso sostenuto
\item Il rapporto capitale/lavoro è cresciuto a un tasso sostenuto
\item Il tasso di profitto sul capitale è stato stabile nei paesi sviluppati
\item Il rapporto capitale/output è rimasto stabile
\item Le quote di profitto e salario sono state stabili
\item Vi sono state differenze dei tassi di crescita tra paesi nell'ordine del 2\%-5\%
\end{enumerate}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: several possibilities really, without showing the input this is not easy to resolve

Comment: perfectly right, I forgot about the input. done.

Comment: Place an empty `\mbox{}` at the bottom of each lists. This may have to do with the way lists terminate and you column breaking.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem here is not related to `multicol` but is in fact a general problem in LaTeX (and not really solvable within the curent LaTeX model (the galley model for LaTeX3 has a solution for this but this doesn't really help with this not operational).

The problem is the following:

The end of the enumerate generates:

- a penalty item (-51 good place to break)
- some extra space

The following section also adds a penalty (-300) and some space before the heading. It tries to be clever and uses `\addpenalty` which looks back and if it sees some space it will cancel that space by adding its negative amount and then adds the penalty and then re-adds the space. As a result we get a sequence like

```
.......\penalty -51
.......\glue 10.0 plus 3.0 minus 5.0
.......\glue -10.0 plus -3.0 minus -5.0
.......\penalty -300
.......\glue 10.0 plus 3.0 minus 5.0
```

The problen now is that `multicol` will see both penalties and obviously it is better to break at -300. As a result the first column ends in those 2 vertical spaces. The cancel each other so they to not generate a "real" space but they result in this column having no depth, i.e., if the last line of text has some characters like "p" inside the bottom of the column is not on the baseline of that last column but below the decenders.

The right hand column on the other hand has no such extra space at its bottom so it has a depth and that alone results second column to appear larger.

If `\columnbreak` is used then it gets worse as it gets into the middle of the sequence so that we get

```
.......\penalty -51
.......\glue 10.0 plus 3.0 minus 5.0
.......\penalty -10005
```

and a full space from enumerate survives. One can argue that this is perhaps a bug but `\columnbreak` follows the way `\pagebreak` works here and simply adds its penalty directly.

This also explains why the workaround using

```
\end{enumerate}
\unskip
\columnbreak
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section*{...
```

with or without the `\columnbreak` gives us the right output: it drops the space after the enumerate so that it does no harm.

Answer (score 13):

While I can't explain the observed behaviour, I have a workaround: Add `\unskip` before `\columnbreak`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,multicol}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{}{1em}{}
\title{Nuovi e vecchi fatti stilizzati}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\maketitle
\begin{multicols}{2}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section*{Kaldor Facts 1961}
\begin{enumerate}
\item La produttività del lavoro è cresciuta a un tasso sostenuto
\item Il rapporto capitale/lavoro è cresciuto a un tasso sostenuto
\item Il tasso di profitto sul capitale è stato stabile nei paesi sviluppati
\item Il rapporto capitale/output è rimasto stabile
\item Le quote di profitto e salario sono state stabili
\item Vi sono state differenze dei tassi di crescita tra paesi nell'ordine del 2\%-5\%
\end{enumerate}
\unskip\columnbreak
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section*{New Kaldor Facts 2009 - Jones, Romer}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item La produttività del lavoro è cresciuta a un tasso sostenuto
\item Il rapporto capitale/lavoro è cresciuto a un tasso sostenuto
\item Il tasso di profitto sul capitale è stato stabile nei paesi sviluppati
\item Il rapporto capitale/output è rimasto stabile
\item Le quote di profitto e salario sono state stabili
\item Vi sono state differenze dei tassi di crescita tra paesi nell'ordine del 2\%-5\%
\end{enumerate}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]