# How to generate "You can't use \unskip in vertical mode"?

Tags: errors, tex-core, programming

We all know (or believe so) that `\unskip` is not possible in main vertical mode and this statement can be found in various answers on the site. And yes LaTeX does a lot of gymnastics in `\addvspace` or `\addpenalty` to deal with this problem. So I was a bit surprised when in [The second column always appears lower than the first one in the multicol environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121692/the-second-column-always-appears-lower-than-the-first-one-in-the-multicol-enviro/121730#121730) a simple workaround using `\unskip` worked.

This was on the main vertical list!

So looking into the TeX program itself, the condition is that the error will be triggered if the last item on the list is a glue item and this glue item has already been contributed to the current page. But when does this happen?

```
XXX
\par
\vskip 1cm 
\vskip 5cm
\unskip\unskip
XXX
\bye
```

This works perfectly and according to the TeXbook there are only 5 cases when stuff gets moved from recent contributions to the current page (page 122):

> Here is a list of the times when that can happen: (a) At the beginning
>   or end of a paragraph, provided that this paragraph is being
>   contributed to the main vertical list. (b) At the beginning or end of
>   a displayed equation within such a paragraph. (c) After completing an
>   `\halign` in vertical mode. (d) After contributing a box or penalty or
>   insertion to the main vertical list. (e) After an `\output` routine
>   has ended.

Unfortunately it is not quite accurate (probably there are some other places discussing this further that I have overlooked). For example, if you add an empty line after the `\vskip` in the example above, then it triggers the error even though that `\par` clearly doesn't trigger or ends any paragraph.

I can imagine to create it from case (e), e.g., by making the output routine add a glue to the main vertical list, though I haven't tried that.

Any other cases in which this could be triggered in reality?

Comment: If the glue is in `\vadjust` then the error is triggered. A `\par` in vertical mode doesn't enter horizontal mode, but exercises the page builder if something is present in the contribution list (second bullet on page 283 of the TeXbook).

Comment: I'm currently reading `@* \[45] The page builder.` from `tex.web`, which seems relevant.  Alternatively, search for `page_tail` or `contrib_head`, which seem to mark the separation between the current page and the recent contributions.

Comment: `\par` in vertical mode calls `normal_paragraph` and `build_page`.  The first sets `\looseness=0`, `\hangindent=0pt`, `\hangafter=1`, `\parshape=0`.  The second moves material from the recent contributions to the current page.  Still investigating on all occurrences of `build_page`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looking at the source `tex.web`, I gather the following, none of which I am sure of.  From the (separate) lines

```
primitive("unskip",remove_item,glue_node);

any_mode(remove_item): delete_last;
```

I see that `\unskip` invokes the procedure `delete_last`, which has the following comment in `tex.web`:

> Like `\lastbox`, this command is not allowed in vertical mode (except
>   internal vertical mode), since the current list in vertical mode is sent
>   to the page builder.  But if we happen to be able to implement it in
>   vertical mode, we do.

In other words, TeX tries its best to remove something, but this is sometimes impossible.  In fact, the code for `delete_last` "apologizes for [the] inability to do the operation now" if the current mode is `vmode` and (I believe) there are no recent contributions, unless `\unskip` follows a non-glue node (in which case `\unskip` does nothing).  Your assessment that we need to find out when things are moved out of the recent contributions is thus correct.

The main vertical list is split into two parts: from `page_head` to `page_tail` lies the current page, and from `contrib_head` to `contrib_tail` lie recent contributions.  Searching for `contrib_`, I find the variables used in several places:

- in the procedure `show_activities`, `link(contrib_head)` is queried, to know if there are any recent contributions;
- the procedure `build_page` appears to move material from the recent contributions to the current page, so it is crucial for us;
- `link(contrib_head):=link(p)` is used in two places to add a node to the recent contributions;
- `q:=new_skip_param(top_skip_code)` then `link(contrib_head):=q` adds the topskip to the page when the first box is added;
- when breaking the page at a given node, whatever follows in the current page is placed before the recent contributions, by manipulating `contrib_head` and `contrib_tail`;
- the default output routine appears to place the current page back into the recent contributions (except of course what has already been split and placed into `\box255`), then shipout `\box255`;
- the same happens after a user-defined output routine (save for the `\box255` business).

From this, we see that `build_page` is probably what you are after.  It is called in the following cases (labelled with a letter corresponding to your list):

- (a) when a paragraph is started in `vmode` (by a horizontal command such as `\indent`, a letter, `\discretionary` etc), after inserting `\everypar` into the input stream;
- (b) after insering the `\everydisplay` token list in the input stream and having set various parameters upon entering display mode, if the surrounding mode is `vmode`;
- (b) after going back to horizontal mode (and saving the language etc) after a display is finished, if the surrounding mode is `vmode`;
- (a) after ending a paragraph with `\par` in horizontal mode if the resulting mode is `vmode`;
- (c) when `\halign` ends in `vmode`;
- (d) after inserting a penalty in `vmode`;
- (d) within the procedure `box_end`, if the finished box (or box register, or...) is non-null and is to be added to the main vertical list (rather than stored, shipped out, or used as a leader);
- (d) when an `\insert` or `\vadjust` ends with an end-group character, if the resulting mode is `vmode`;
- (e) after TeX has finished a user's output routine, checked that `\box255` is empty, and placed all the current page material into recent contributions (see above);
- when encountering `\par` in `vmode`;
- after inserting `\hbox to \hsize{}\vfill\penalty-'10000000000` if there is still some material in the main vertical list when meeting the primitive `\end`.

A few differences crop up compared to your list.  After a default output routine, `build_page` does not seem to be used.  The case of `\end` is missing from your list.  More importantly, the case of `\par` in unrestricted vertical mode is not explicitly given in your list (although (a) would fit it, I guess).  This case explains why

```
XXX\par
\vskip 1cm
%
\unskip
```

fails upon removing the `%`.  Contrarily to expectations, `\par` in vertical mode is not ignored: it moves material from the recent contributions to the current page, but also resets some parameters (`\looseness`, `\hangindent`, `\hangafter` and `\parshape`).  This comes to me as a surprise.

I found one last thing.  The procedure `build_page` is not used in `append_glue` because the procedure `append_glue` "is used in at least one place where that would be a mistake".  I do not know where the mistake would be.  But this explains why `\vskip 1cm` does not make TeX move any material to the current page.