# Suppress a \smallskip at page/column bottom

Tags: spacing, multicol

I have a command that works similar to this simplified command:

```
\newcommand{\revEntry}{#1}{
    #1

    \smallskip
}
```

In my document I have *lots* of such entries in a multicolumn environment, and now I see that when such an entry is at a column bottom - and is followed by a `\columnbreak`, the `\smallskip` is 'printed' at the end of the page.

How can I make the `\smallskip` conditional so it is only printed when *not* at the page/column bottom?

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newcommand{\test}{
    Test command.

    \bigskip
}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}
\test
\test

%\unskip
%\vskip-\lastskip
\columnbreak
\test
\test

Test paragraph.

Test paragraph.

Test paragraph.

Test paragraph.

Test paragraph.

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see at the end of the first column where I have the manual column break the `\bigskip` is 'printed'.

Using `\unskip` as suggested results in 'You can't use \unskip in vertical mode', the other solution with negative \lastskip doesn't have any effect. Maybe because the skip is 'hidden' inside the macro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with `\vskip-\lastskip` is that there are two vertical skips here, one from the paragraph break and one from the `\smallskip`.

You can avoid this by using those two commands:

```
\newcommand\mybigskip{\addvspace\bigskipamount}
\newcommand\mycolumnbreak{\vskip-\lastskip\columnbreak}
```

`\addvspace` is an internal LaTeX command which will make sure a previous vertical space is "undone".

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. But I've added a MWE.

Comment: I will look into it. I managed to achieve what I want with the first version of this answer. I'm going to see if I first did something wrong or if something is wrong with one of my LaTeX's

Comment: Your original solution with `\newcommand{\mycolumnbreak}{\unskip\unskip}` did work too. But only when there is no empty line (paragraph) between `\test` and `\mycolumnbreak`. Otherwise I get an error about `\unskip not allowed in vertical mode.`. So this solution is cleaner and more robust. Thanks.

Comment: @uli_1973 Sorry for creating confusion with my first solution attempt. I was under the (false) impression that typesetting in `multicols` does not happen on the main vertical list. And my own test file went through, so I did not suspect. I [asked in the chat for explanation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12335000#12335000) and was pointed to [a deeper discussion of the subject](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121737/how-to-generate-you-cant-use-unskip-in-vertical-mode) (which btw. contains a link to a question similar to yours :-)

Comment: OK. I'll try to remember the second solution. But I got my document to work with the first version, and I won't fiddle around with it anymore, now that I've uploaded it to the printer ;-) (Actually this issue popped out at the *very last* moment before publication. Of course I wanted to manually fix column breaking in my list only after any proof-reading itself was finished so I never noticed the issue before ...