# Strange tikz problem (memoir vs xcolor vs tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, memoir

Consider the MWE below, on a fully updated TeX Live 2015, this gives me this error:

```
/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.meta.co
de.tex:208: You can't use `\unskip' in vertical mode.
<recently read> \unskip 

l.208 }
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
% if xcolor is removed, file compiles
\usepackage{xcolor}
% if \SingleSpacing is removed, file compiles
\SingleSpacing
\usepackage{tikz}
% arrows.meta removed, file compiles
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

test

\end{document}
```

As listed remove one of the three, and the example compiles.

I'm guessing this is somehow related to `\SingleSpacing`, a `memoir` macro defined as

```
\newcommand*{\SingleSpacing}{%
  \setSpacing{\m@m@singlespace}%
  \edef\m@m@footnote@spacing{\baselinestretch}%
  \edef\m@m@float@spacing{\baselinestretch}%
  \vskip\baselineskip% correction for coming into single spacing
}
```

if I remove the `\vskip` it works again.

Any idea what on earth is going on here?

Can others reproduce the problem?

Comment: `tikz` later calls `xcolor`.

Comment: @Johannes_B, I know, but that does not explain the error. Also in my real document I need to pass options to `xcolor`, options that does not seem to be relevant here.

Comment: No, it doesn't explain the error. I can reproduce it, by the way. You can add the options globally  when loading documentclass. They will be passed to `xcolor`.

Comment: Yep, I can reproduce the problem. So, not something wrong with your installation.

Comment: The problem is the \vskip\baselineskip. If you add it directly before loading the library you get the error. Not loading xcolor probably "hides" it as xcolor will be loaded by tikz.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I know, but it does not explain why it is problematic.

Comment: While unskip is not allowed in vertical mode it is normally harmless to use it there -- unless there is glue before, then it will complain. See e.g. the answer of Bruno http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121737/how-to-generate-you-cant-use-unskip-in-vertical-mode. xcolor separate the \vskip from the \unskip (inserted by `\pdfmathsetlength`) because it inserts at the end a color command.

Comment: As of `memoir` 3.7h `\SingleSpacing` will no longer emit a `\vskip` when used in the preamble.

Answer (score 4):

As diagnosed by @UlrikeFischer, the problem originates in an `\unskip` issued by `\pgfmathsetlength` under certain circumstances.

I don't know the innards of `TikZ`, but here is a re-definition of the first branch of `\pgfmathsetlength` which uses a temporary box, as it apparently needs to issue a `\selectfont` and then an `\unskip` (presumably to get rid of some extraneous space following some dimension definition).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\SingleSpacing

%\tracingmacros1
%\def\unskip{\BOOM}
\usepackage{tikz}
\typeout{Original meaning of pgfmathsetlength\meaning\pgfmathsetlength}


\newbox\tempbox
\newif\ifdebug
\debugtrue

\makeatletter
\def\pgfmathsetlength #1#2{\expandafter \pgfmath@onquick #2\pgfmath@ 
  {\ifdebug\typeout{HERE\detokenize{#1}\detokenize{#2}}\fi
   \setbox\tempbox\hbox{\pgfmath@selectfont#1#2\relax\expandafter}\expandafter#1\the #1\relax 
   \ifdebug\typeout{#1=\the#1}\fi}%
  {\pgfmathparse {#2}\ifpgfmathmathunitsdeclared #1\pgfmathresult mu\relax 
                     \else #1\pgfmathresult pt\relax \fi }\ignorespaces }
\makeatother

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{bending}
\begin{document}

% from the manual
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [circle,draw] (A) {A};
\node [circle,draw] (B) [right=of A] {B};
\draw [draw = blue, thick,
       arrows={
              Computer Modern Rightarrow [sep]
              - Latex[blue!50,length=8pt,bend,line width=0pt]
                Stealth[length=8pt,open,bend,sep]}]
      (A) edge [bend left=45] (B)
      (B) edge [in=-110, out=-70,looseness=8] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: That is one strange bug. Thanks for the run through